# how to check table fragmentation in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

How to check whether table has been fragmented or not. I have googled it but dint get satisfactory response. what should be the ideal time or period to analyze the table.

Comment: The ideal time is perhaps once every three years. There are a plenty of more important things to worry about. Fragmentation is one of those things that we check for when our system seems to be running slow and we don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

what is your definition of fragmentation? Jonathan Lewis has given a good definition in https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/fragmentation-1/. I think, it's hard to tell, when a table should be reorganized to reclaim space, that is no longer used. Ignoring LOBs, compression and other special cases, you can compare the actual size of a segment (in `dba_segments`) with the value you get by the multiplication of `num_rows` with `avg_row_len` in `user_tables` (after a statistics gathering) - but I would hesitate to define a threshold signalizing the need for a rebuild; especially since this rebuild will change the physical order of rows and conequently the `clustering factor` of related indexes: and this means - their efficiency.